# ошибка Flask в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Делаю свой API на flask и возникла проблема с регистрацией

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
def register():
    loginw = request.args.get('login')
    passw = request.args.get('passw')
    if users[loginw] is None:
        users[1] = {'name': loginw, 'passw': passw}
        return 'Вы зарегистрировались!'
    else:
        return 'Этот пользователь уже зарегистрирован'
```

Когда я перехожу по /register?login=hello&passw=rerere
то пишет вместо вы зарегистрировались пишет:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
а users у меня это
users = {}

Comment: Потому что если нет такого ключа, то программа выдаст ошибку KeyError.

Comment: так я же сделал проверку if users[loginw] is None

Comment: Так в этом и проблема в users нет loginw, он возращает не None в случае отсутствия ключа, а ошибку.

Comment: Проверка должна быть такая not loginw in users

Comment: попробую сделать

Comment: Только у вас там дальше проблема users[1] -- это очень странное поведение...

Comment: Вам надо было users[loginw] = passw по вашей логике